# `pg_restore` unable to read `toc.dat` created by `pg_dump -Fd`: `pg_restore: error: expected format (1) differs from format found in file (3)`

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

The `pg_dump -Fd mydb -f mydb.dump` command creates a `mydb.dump` directory with a `toc.dat` file. The [`pg_dump` man page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) mentions that [`pg_restore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) is able to read this file, but after skimming [its man page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) and stumbling upon [this PostgreSQL mailing list thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/547C8D10.40800@aklaver.com), I get this cryptic error:

```
$ pg_restore -l mydb.dump/toc.dat

pg_restore: error: expected format (1) differs from format found in file (3)
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** `pg_restore` expects the a **directory** when reading from directory dumps:

```
pg_restore -l <dump_directory_name>
```

So, in the case above, it is `pg_restore -l mydb.dump`.

---

After a more careful reading of the [`pg_restore` man page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html), I found the `-F` option:

> **-F format**
> **--format=format**
> Specify format of the archive. It is not necessary to specify the format, since `pg_restore` will determine the format automatically. If specified, it can be one of the following:
> (`c` custom, `d` directory, `t` tar)

So I tried `pg_restore -l mydb.dump/toc.dat -Fd` next; the result:

```
pg_restore: error: could not open input file "mydb.dump/toc.dat/toc.dat": Not a directory
```

Then `pg_restore -l mydb.dump -Fd`, which worked, so I gave it try deleting `-Fd` from the end, which also did.

**update**: Could have avoided this experimentation if I had actually paid attention to the man page (emphasis mine):

> #### Options
>
> `pg_restore` accepts the following command line arguments.
>
> **filename**
> Specifies the location of the archive file (*or **directory**, for a **directory-format archive***) to be restored. If not specified, the standard input is used.